# Question - Crashlytics report not accurate

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have successfully integrated Firebase into my project using Cocoapods with environments

Crashlytics (3.14.0)
Fabric (1.10.2)
FirebaseAnalytics (6.2.1)
Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500)
iOS version 12

All crash logs successfully showed up in Crashlytics Dashboard (with uploading Crashlytics symbols -dSYM- zip file using new Firebase Distribution) but the result not accurate, what I mean by that is all crashes should mark the line, class and file to indicate where it happened, right?

instead I got crash log like this

[image]

for more details also this

[image]

My code that I wrote to force crash like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellll")!
    }
}
```

even both Keys and Logs are empty, but it's clear that I'm force unwrapping cell which basically is `nil`.

[image]

So my question is what I'm missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any missing dSYMs under your Crashlytics Dashboard's dSYM section? This is a partially symbolicated crash report, this can happen if there are missing dSYMs. Also, make sure that you set your keys and logs before the crash occurs. If the crash occurs before these are triggered, then they won't show up with the crash report.

Comment: No missing dSYMs under Crashlytics Dashboard's dSYM section, on other hand I have Bugsnag crash report which describe exactly where crash happened and why did it happen. I don't have custom Keys so far, it just random crash may occur any where!

Comment: This can also happen due to the presence of multiple crash reporters in your app. Can you write to in at https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact with the link of this crash? Also reference this SO post.